# Throwing an rvalue

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14, throw

Consider the fragment:

```
try {
    Foo f;
    throw std::move(f);
}
catch (Foo& f) { }
```

[expr.throw] says that:

> the type of the exception object
>   is determined by removing any top-level *cv-qualifiers* from the static type of the operand and adjusting the
>   type from “array of T” or “function returning T” to “pointer to T” or “pointer to function returning T”,
>   respectively.

which would be `Foo&&`. The exception object is then initialized according to [except.throw]:

> Throwing an exception copy-initializes (8.5, 12.8) a temporary object, called the *exception object*. The
>   temporary is an lvalue and is used to initialize the variable declared in the matching *handler* (15.3). If the
>   type of the exception object would be an incomplete type or a pointer to an incomplete type other than
>   (possibly cv-qualified) `void` the program is ill-formed.

This suggests to me that the exception object is initialized as:

```
Foo&& __exception_object = std::move(f);
```

and that the handler would not match. However, both gcc and clang do catch this exception. So what's the actual type of the exception object here? If `Foo`, why?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The static type of an expression is never a reference type.

1.3.24 [defns.static.type] defines "static type":

> type of an expression (3.9) resulting from analysis of the program without considering execution semantics

the first step in that "analysis of the program" is to remove references, see
5 [expr] p5 and [Expressions can have reference type](http://scottmeyers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/expressions-can-have-reference-type.html)

> If an expression initially has the type “reference to `T`” (8.3.2, 8.5.3), the type is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference, and  the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the expression.

So `std::move(f)` is an xvalue expression, with static type `Foo`.

You don't need to involve rvalues to demonstrate this, the same was true in C++03 with:

```
int& f();
throw f();
```

This throws an `int` not an `int&`.

Without considering the specifics, an exception object is an object, and a reference is not an object, so an exception object cannot be a reference. It must be an object.